# SpringBoot migration 2.6.15 to 2.7.0 error: because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, webview

I did upgrade from spring boot **2.6.15** to **2.7.0**

More about my set up:

**html thymeleaf page named myPage.html**

is in directory **myproject/src/main/resources/templates/html/myPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" th:href="@{/img/favicon.png}" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/app/myApp.js}" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**myApp.js**

is in directory **myproject/src/main/resources/static/js/app/myApp.js**

**spring controller**

```
package com.myapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ViewController {

  @GetMapping("/myPage")
  public String myPage() {
    return "html/myPage";
  }

}
```

Before update to spring boot 2.7.0 I was able to load this html page containing javascript in my android app and everything was working fine using this code to load

```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080/myPage");
```

After update to springboot 2.7.0

I'm receiving an error:

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/js/app/myApp.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.", source: http://localhost/myPage (0)

I was trying to find in release notes what was changed with MIME, Content-Type etc. but I found nothing https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes
I also have checked deprecation list from 2.5.0 https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/deprecated-list.html
but again nothing. Maybe some body of you know what could happen and how to fix that?

Edit:

I have tried SpringBoot version 2.7.13 but the error remain the same.

Curl for both 2.6.15 and 2.7.13 but result are the same.

**2.6.15:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: origin,access-control-request-method,access-control-request-headers,accept-encoding
Last-Modified: Sat, 08 Jul 2023 08:49:59 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 2453575
Date: Sat, 08 Jul 2023 12:02:28 GMT
```

**2.7.13:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: origin,access-control-request-method,access-control-request-headers,accept-encoding
Last-Modified: Sat, 08 Jul 2023 08:49:59 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 2453575
Date: Sat, 08 Jul 2023 11:53:14 GMT
```

There must be some change in spring serving content-type but how to track it?

Comment: I would upgrade to 2.7.13 rather than 2.7.0. If that doesn't help, if you `curl -i http://localhost/js/app/myApp.js` with 2.6.15 and 2.7.13 what output do you get in each case?

Comment: Both those responses look fine to me so It's not clear why the browser would complain about one and not the other. Please update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve).